# Vue.js - Pagination

Tags: pagination, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following pagination component.

If users adds remove items dynamically i.e via some ajax call, how do i ensure the correct active or disabled classes are applied on the pagination links?

For example if the user is currently on the last page which only has 1 item, if the user deletes that item, the pagination links re-render but then i lose the active disable class becuase that page no longer exists. i.e. the links should update to move the user to previous page.

```
 <div class="comment-pager ">
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-highlight no-border ">
        <div class="panel-body padded-5">
            <nav v-if="totalItems > pageSize">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li v-bind:class="[currentPage == 1 ? disabled : '']">
                        <a v-on:click.prevent="previous()" aria-label="Previous">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li v-bind:class="[currentPage == pages ? active : '']" v-for="page in pages" v-on:click.prevent="changePage(page)">
                        <a>{{ page }}</a>
                    </li>
                    <li v-bind:class="[currentPage == pages.length ? disabled : '']">
                        <a v-on:click.prevent="next()" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>  
        </div>
   </div>
</div>     


</template>

<script>

export default {

    props: ['totalItems', 'pageSize']

    data: function () {

        return {
            currentPage: 1,
            pages: [],
        }

    },

    watch: {
        totalItems: function () {

           var pagesCount = Math.ceil(this.totalItems / this.pageSize); 
           this.pages = [];
           for (var i = 1; i <= pagesCount; i++)
            this.pages.push(i);  
        }
    },

    methods: {

        changePage: function (page){

            this.currentPage = page; 
            this.$emit('pageChanged', page);
        }

        previous: function (){
            if (this.currentPage == 1)
                return;

            this.currentPage--;

            this.$emit('pageChanged', this.currentPage);
        }

        next: function () {
            if (this.currentPage == this.pages.length)
                return; 

            this.currentPage++;

            this.$emit('pageChanged', this.currentPage);
        }
    },

}


</script>

  <paginator v-bind:total-items="totalItems" v-bind:page-size="query.pageSize" v-on:pageChanged="onPageChange"></paginator>
```

Comment: please upvote all answers which give you any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no complete equivalent to `ngOnChanges()` in vue.

`ngOnChanges()` is a lifecycle hook which takes in an object that maps each changed property name to a **SimpleChange** object holding the current and previous property values.

If you want the lifecycle hook that gets invoked after every change in `data` and before re-rendering the virtual DOM then you should be using [`beforeUpdate()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated)  hook.

But as in `ngOnChanges()` you can't get the hold of which property is updated or what is it's oldvalue or newValue is.

As **mklimek** answered you can set up [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the properties you want to watch for changes.

In watcher you get what the oldValue is and what it's changed new value is

```
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        prop1: '',
        prop2: '' // property to watch changes for
    },
    watch:{
        prop@(newValue, oldValue){
            console.log(newValue);
            console.log(oldValue);
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

For your case you do not need a watcher. You can setup the `pages[]` property as a computed property:

```
computed:{
    pages(){
        var pageArray = [];
        var pagesCount = Math.ceil(this.totalItems / this.pageSize); 
        
        for (var i = 1; i <= pagesCount; i++)
            pages.push(i);
        }
        return pageArray;
}
```

[computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) are cached based on their dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed in your case the props
`totalItems` and `pageSize`

Now you can use the `pages` computed property as normal `data` property

Comment: please can you have a look at my updated code and advise how I replicate the `ngOnChanges()` code in my vue.js paginator?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363283/how-to-display-content-by-page-number-or-prev-next-clicked-on-the-vue

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) property of a Vue instance.

```
 var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    count: 1
  },
  watch: {
    count: function (val, oldVal) {
      console.log('new: %s, old: %s', val, oldVal)
    }
})
```